# jQuery error in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am calling a jQuery function as follows, where `$.fn.myfunction = function(task) { ... }` is defined in the `$(document).ready() { ... }` function.

```
$('#update').myFunction(task);
```

I'm getting the following error.

> Object doesn't support this property or method

How do I fix this?

Comment: Edited, and added the `internet-explorer` tag but, _which version are you using_?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a capitalization error:

```
$('#update').myFunction(task);
//             ^--- capital `F`
```

compared with

```
$.fn.myfunction = ...
//     ^--- lower case `f`
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Other than that, I'm assuming you're calling `$('#update').myFunction(task);` *after* setting up the function on `$.fn`. If you fix the capitalization and ensure you're doing them in the right order, it should work fine.

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/ipovin)